# Changing font size using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to use document.getElementById to change the font size of some text, but for some reason it's not changing and it's staying at 200%. What am I doing wrong.

```
#detail {
font-size: 200%;
}

<div id = "detail"> Hello World <div>

<script type = "text/javascript">

if (true) {
document.getElementById(detail).style["font-size"] = "100%";
}

</script>
```

Comment: @tymeJV Is all dashes turn into camelCase when we use document.getElementById instead of style?

Comment: `getElementById(detail)` should be `getElementById('detail')` since `detail` is a `string` and not a variable name.

Comment: @chris85 Just an example to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. It's not actually going to be if (true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have some quotes on detail. and try detail.style.fontSize instead of detail.style["font-size"]

```
var detail = document.getElementById("detail");
detail.style.fontSize = "100%";
```

Comment: Both `detail.style["font-size"]` and `detail.style.fontSize` are identical.

Comment: thanks, good to know about "font-size".  I have never used it that way.

Comment: No prob - this works for more than just `.style`; dot-syntax and array-syntax can be used anywhere when accessing object properties.